# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] (trying to connect via (null)) when connecting to digitalocean managed db

Tags: php, laravel, cloud, digital-ocean

I am using digitalocean managed DB in my laravel app . Everything working fine in tinker mode but when using in app it throws
`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] (trying to connect via (null))` 
error . even i can connect it from beekeeper studio.
here's my configuration.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=obilia-***.db.ondigitalocean.com
DB_PORT=25060
DB_DATABASE=defaultdb
DB_USERNAME=**********
DB_PASSWORD=**********
DB_SSLMODE=required
MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA=storage/cert/ca-certificate.crt
```